# Как передать значение input type="file" по localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Подскажите как сделать? Смысл - на одной странице `index.html` к которой прикреплен `app.js` пользователь выбирает аудиофайл, а на другой `result.html` и `result.js` - он запускается в плеере. При использовании localStorage значение `File` передается, но в переменной `path` которая берет значение из `localStorage` лежит уже не `File`  а `[object File]` . В результате - появляется вот такая ошибка `GET file:///D:/education/DREAM_STARTING/2020/trainer/result/[object%20File] net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`
Я передаю также имя файла по `localStorage nameaudio` - тут все нормально.
Как сделать, чтобы проигрыватель запускался? Вот код

```
index.html:

<span>Выберите аудиофайл на своем устройстве:</span>
                <input id="input1" type="file">
<div id ="but_go"  class="go"><span>Go</span></div>

app.js:

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#but_go').on('click', function () { 
    var nameaudioinindexhtml = document.getElementById('input1').files[0].name;
    var arrinindexhtml =input1.files[0];
    localStorage.setItem('audioname_ls', nameaudioinindexhtml);
    localStorage.setItem('arr_ls', arrinindexhtml);

result.js:

            let path = localStorage.getItem('arr_ls'),
            nameaudio = localStorage.getItem('audioname_ls');
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    let Song,  songs = [0,'Песня_1'];
   function playNewSong(id) {
            let duration; 
            Song = new Audio();
            Song.src = path;
            Song.onloadeddata = function(){
                duration = Song.duration;
                songs.push(duration);
                songs.push(nameaudio);
                Song.play(); ... вот с этого места появляется ошибка
               .....код
```

Comment: Не надо передавать через localStorage - он имеет ограничение на размер, вы не сможете записать туда большой файл. Выхода два - загружать пользовательский файл на сервер. Или сделать проигрывание файла на той же странице.

Comment: Да, около 2мб можно вроде передавать. Этого за глаза. ведь я передаю только имя и путь. Я еще только начинаю изучать языки программирования и в серверное пока не вникал, хочу сделать что-нибудь попроще.

Comment: Ну в том то и дело, что путь не надо передавать. Нельзя через браузер считывать файлы с клиентского копмпа по пути (за ооооочень редкими исключениями). Поэтому ваша идея сохранять путь до файла - не подойдет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно преобразовать файл в Blob-ссылку и ставить в localStorage уже её

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#but_go').on('click', function () { 
    let audioName = $('#input1').files[0].name,
        audioURL = URL.createObjectURL($('#input1').files[0]);

    localStorage.setItem('audioname_ls', audioName);
    localStorage.setItem('arr_ls', audioURL);
  });
});
```

Comment: Да, передача произошла, но появилось сообщение Not allowed to load local resource: и файл не запустился. Ни в опере ни в хроме

Comment: Вот такая же проблема, попробуйте запустить сценарии на http сервере: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682978/getting-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-error-while-trying-to-attach-a-medi

Comment: Да познавательно. но только, чтобы у пользователя моего ресурса trenajor.me это получилось надо установить сервер на пк. НЕУДОБНО. Поэтому реализую выбор файла уже на конечной странице result.html ДРУГОГО ПРОСТО НЕ ВИЖУ ПРАВИЛЬНОГО ВАРИАНТА. Загружать пользователю каждый раз файл на сервер а потом читать - тоже неудобно.

Comment: нет, не нужно. Вы будете хостить приложение на сервере и пользователю устанавливать его не надо

Comment: и если этот ответ правильный, то отметьте его как решение

Comment: Хорошо бы упомянуть про максимальный размер файла, который можно передать таким способом.